# Group on field while getting the last document for each field with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

## Problem

I'm trying to group a stock inventory by products. At first, my stock entries was fully filled each time so I made this aggregate:

```
[
  { $sort: { date: 1 } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: '$userId',
      stocks: { $last: '$stocks' },
    },
  },
  { $unwind: '$stocks' },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: '$stocks.productId',
      totalQuantity: { $sum: '$stocks.quantity' },
      stocks: { $push: { userId: '$_id', quantity: '$stocks.quantity' } },
    },
  },
]
```

Now, it can be possible that a stock entry doesn't contain all the products filled. So I'm stuck while writing the new aggregate.

Basically I need to group every products by `productId` and have an array of the last entry for each user.

## Output

This is my expected output:

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5e75eae1359fc8159d5b6073"),
    "totalQuantity": 33,
    "stocks": [
      {
        "userId": ObjectId("5e75f498359fc8159d5b6075"),
        "lastDate": "2020-03-21T11:45:53.077Z",
        "quantity": 33
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5e75eaea359fc8159d5b6074"),
    "totalQuantity": 2,
    "stocks": [
      {
        "userId": ObjectId("5e75f498359fc8159d5b6075"),
        "lastDate": "2020-03-21T11:45:53.077Z",
        "quantity": 2
      }
    ]
  } 
]
```

## Documents

Documents (when fully filled):

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5e75fe71e4a3e0323ba47e0a"),
  "date": "2020-03-21T11:45:53.077Z",
  "userId": ObjectId("5e75f498359fc8159d5b6075"),
  "stocks": [
    {
      "productId": ObjectId("5e75eae1359fc8159d5b6073"),
      "quantity": 33
    },
    {
      "productId": ObjectId("5e75eaea359fc8159d5b6074"),
      "quantity": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

Sometimes it won't be filled for the whole inventory (that's why I need the `lastDate`):

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5e75fe71e4a3e0323ba47e0a"),
  "date": "2020-03-21T11:45:53.077Z",
  "userId": ObjectId("5e75f498359fc8159d5b6075"),
  "stocks": [
    {
      "productId": ObjectId("5e75eae1359fc8159d5b6073"),
      "quantity": 33
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$userId",
      root: {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      root: {
        $map: {
          input: "$root",
          as: "data",
          in: {
            "stocks": {
              $map: {
                input: "$$data.stocks",
                as: "stock",
                in: {
                  "productId": "$$stock.productId",
                  "userId": "$$data.userId",
                  "quantity": "$$stock.quantity",
                  "lastDate": "$$data.date"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$root"
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: "$root"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$stocks"
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      "stocks.lastDate": 1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$stocks.productId",
      totalQuantity: {
        $last: "$stocks.quantity"
      },
      stocks: {
        $last: "$stocks"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      stocks: [
        {
          "lastDate": "$stocks.lastDate",
          "quantity": "$stocks.quantity",
          "userId": "$stocks.userId"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Sc7okH1TbCX)